# How to prevent Rails HTML sanitizer from removing style attribute in a template?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activestorage, actionview, actiontext

I'm converting ActionText HTML into PDF using [Prawn-Markup](https://github.com/puzzle/prawn-markup/). I need large images to be scaled down (not resized or cropped), which requires setting the width in the style attribute, which Prawn-Markup then forwards to Prawn.
Unfortunately, the style attribute is removed by Rails' Sanitizer when rendering the template.

```rb
# app/views/active_storage/blobs/_blob.html.erb
image_tag blob, style: "width: #{blob.metadata[:whidth]}px"
# => "<img style=\"width: 200px\" src=\"...\" />

# app/views/action_text/content/_layout.html.erb
# => "<img src=\"...\" />
```

The style attribute needs to be preserved when rendering blobs, but I don't want to disable style sanitization for the entire app.

Any idea how to achieve that?

EDIT:
I was able to allow `style` attributes in actiontext by adding it to the `ActionText::Attachment::ATTRIBUTES` in an initializer, which works for blobs, but leaves actiontext open to abuse. Still searching…

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
ActionText::Content::ALLOWED_ATTRIBUTES.add 'style'
```

Or:

```
# config/initializers/action_text.rb
# frozen_string_literal: true

# You can also add a check to make sure the style attribute is only allowed for images:

module ActionText
  class Content
    ATTRIBUTES = %w[
      # ...
    ].freeze

    def sanitize
      # ...
      ATTRIBUTES << 'style' if node.name == 'img'
      # ...
    end
  end
end
```